# I'm using the ruby gem "roo" to read xlsx file, how to return the content of one column as an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, xlsx

```
require 'gchart'
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'

oo = Excelx.new("datav.xlsx")
oo.default_sheet = oo.sheets.first
2.upto(47) do |line|
  data_a = [oo.cell(line,'B')]
  data_b = [oo.cell(line,'E')]

  chart_a = Gchart.new( :type => 'line',
                        :title => "A",
                        :theme => :keynote,
                        :width => 600,
                        :height => 500,
                        :data => data_a, 
                        :line_colors => 'e0440e',
                        :axis_with_labels => ['x', 'y'], 
                        :axis_range => [[0,50,20], [0,3000,500]],
                        :filename => "tmp/chart_a.png")

  chart_b = Gchart.new( :type => 'line',
                        :title => "B",
                        :theme => :keynote,
                        :width => 600,
                        :height => 500,
                        :data => data_b, 
                        :line_colors => 'e62ae5',
                        :axis_with_labels => ['x', 'y'], 
                        :axis_range => [[0,50,20], [0,3000,500]],
                        :filename => "tmp/chart_b.png")

  # Record file in filesystem
  chart_a.file
  chart_b.file

end
```

This will get every cell's content of column B and E to be the argument :data alone. How to return it as an array?    If roo can't return array, then is there any else gem do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a `column` method that returns values of a given column as an array. Calling `oo.column(2)` should return you values for column B. `oo.column('B')` might work also. haven't tested it.

Comment: Tested it, didn't work. `column` is not a method of the class `Excelx`.

Comment: http://roo.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html  - according to docs its there... look at column method in docs. it is in GenericSpreadsheet which is Base class for all other types of spreadsheets. Maybe you are calling it on wrong object?

Comment: I'm using Roo v1.10.1. But I'v found another way to get the array.

Comment: Use `column` method is the best way to return an array.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the row back as a hash to be compatible with the logic I used for FasterCSV. This will give you a hash of the first row as the key and current line as the value.

```
def row_from_excel(s, line)
  row = {}
  s.first_column.upto(s.last_column) do |col|
    cell_name = s.cell(1, col)
    logger.debug "************* #{col} => #{cell_name} => #{s.cell(line, col)}"
    row[cell_name] = s.cell(line, col)      
  end

  row    
end

s = Excelx.new(path_to_file) # or Excel.new(path_to_file)
2.upto(s.last_row) do |line|
  row = row_from_excel(s, line)
end
```